# Is there something like a Thing as a Service (TaaS) emerging in the field of IoT and IIoT?

Tags: web-services

There is a quite a lot of development in **PaaS** (Platform as a Service) and **SaaS** (Service as a Service) in the fields of Cloud Computing. However I was thinking of a scenario where

> An end user/ firm would actually like to hire some *things* which do sensing in an environment (Industrial, Environmental) which the end user need not have. Hence, perhaps something like **Thing as a Service (TaaS)**

The only closest thing that I can relate to this is Testbeds where you can conducts tests and experiments but I am looking whether, there might be some Commercial solutions too for this "concept".

Comment: Despite the close votes, this is an interesting question. Is there any way that the OP could rephrase it to make it on-topic?

Comment: @Mawg Maybe a discussion in the meta stack would lead to something?

Comment: Good idea (+1). Can a moderator migrate it, or should the OP delete this & post to meta?

Comment: I have added a vote to push to the meta stack. Need votes for the same.

Comment: Lolx - I only just noted that you are the OP :-) An interesting question, which I will follow

Comment: Following up on my comments to your meta post: "Are there any ____?" posts are often not received well by the community. I don't think they're necessarily a bad question format, but they're often broad which can be a difficulty for answerers. It's particularly hard for answerers to say either "yes, your idea does exist" or "no, it does not" (proving it doesn't exist is difficult without exhaustively checking every possible implementation of an idea similar to this). It might also help to clarify why you're interested in the answer — are you looking to implement the model yourself?

Comment: @Aurora0001 I have undeleted the question but probably will rephrase it with a little more precise information to make this question more valuable